# Filter out repeated entries in a data set tally

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a data set of players and their corresponding jersey numbers. My actual data set is larger but this sample should suffice for all intents and purposes. This data set includes the various specialties that the player has. There are categories that each specialty (sport) falls into. Albeit the formatting, I was able to get some valuable help earlier this week which helped me in arriving at a total tally for a numeric category in a cell with other numbers and commas.

The function that helped me was as follows:

```
=SUM(--(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,SUBSTITUTE($D$3:$D$16,",","</s><s>"))&"</s></t>","//s[.=" & K3 & "]")<>""))
```

However, in the data I have now, there are situations where one player will play two games which both fall into the same category (i.e., player 10 plays Soccer and Baseball and they both are sports that require a ball). What I want, is to be able to find the # of players that play a single sport that falls into one of the many categories. For example, I would like to find the number of players that play a single sport that requires a ball. So if a player plays two sports that require a ball, the tally should only count this player once. Is there a function that can allow me to avoid double counting of players across a designated category? I have also attached a screenshot of my excel worksheet below.

[image: Excel Player Worksheet Screenshot]

Comment: so do a countifs() based on name & game and if the result is greater than 1 use an if() to show 1.

Comment: @SolarMike I'm not sure how one would do that, given that the COUNTIF runs into issues when analyzing a categorization with more than one number (i.e., a cell with the values 1,12 asked to find instances of 1 will run into issues). Maybe I'm not understanding what you are saying. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Well, provide example data so I don't have to type and I might consider it. But you really should try reading the help on countifs() and testing for yourself. IF() is so simple once countifs() is sorted.

Comment: @SolarMike What would be the format of what you are stating? Like you said, =COUNTIIF(IF(***),**)? or =COUNTIF(**,IF(***))? Also, does this method account for the fact that there are commas in the cell set? Not sure how to insert an excel spreadsheet into stack overflow.

Comment: well, I was thinking along the lines of: if(iferror(countifs(...,...),0)>1,1,"") as a structure. Hopefully you can work with that. You don't need to post a sheet, just dfata in a table that can be copied. And to give you a clue how to deal with the question you asked on the answer you got try unique().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved (and edited)

I'm using Array formulas and "COUNTA" for solve both the [total tally] and the [player count] problems.

Formula for total tally:
->>> =COUNTA(FILTER($E$3:$E$30,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(","&H3&",",","&$E$3:$E$30&",",1)))))

[image]

Formula for player count:
->>> =COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$3:$C$30,NOT(ISERROR(FIND(","&H3&",",","&$E$3:$E$30&",",1))))))

[image]

Comment: Let me know if that's what you're looking for, I find this easier to follow than filterxml

Comment: This formula works really well. However, how can I have it continue to work when I have 20 categories and I don't want the 11,12,13... to be counted as a 1,2 or 3 category?

Comment: oo. good point. I think I have a solution. One Sec.

Comment: Okay... It's not nearly as cute and pretty... but it works. I'm editing my post now.

Comment: Hey @Cameron Critchlow, the total tally function works like a charm. However, the formula for player count does not seem to get the actual value. The screenshot says that there are 4 counts of category 2 for player 2. I might also be reading your representation incorrectly. If you could provide some clarification on the last column, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want to know the number of players that play a category 2 game right? 
Player10 plays 2 Cat2 games, player11 plays 2 Cat2 games, player12 plays 1 cat2 game, player13 plays 1 cat2 game. No other players play any cat 2 games.  
This Equals 6 games played in total, and 4 players playing them. 
 Is this what you wanted?

Comment: Oh Yes, sorry I was not understanding my data haha. Thank you so much this works perfectly. Hope your day is going well!